# Asterisk : reconnecting to remote mySQL?

Tags: mysql, odbc, asterisk

How set up asterisk server reconnect  to remote MySQL server if connection lost ?
Asterisk 1.8.32.3  with odbc support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk have cdr and realtime connection. Both WILL reconnect on NEXT access attempt.

There are no way do something if connection lost while asterisk do query. Only variant - redo query using dialplan check.

You also can use connection pool to pre-connect to database(see res_odbc.conf.sample)

Comment: So I mean cdr database connection. When I start asterisk on server it connects to remote host, but after some time lost connection and don`t reconnect again.

Comment: I am sure it do reconnect when new cdr arive. If your one not able reconnect, you have check what is issue. But it is not asterisk for sure. Most of mysql installation have connection timeout set to something like 10hrs, so in almost all freepbx installs it DO reconnect every day.